# Example for use of `citeproc` in Haskell code needed?

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I try to upgrade a program converting blog entries using `pandoc` from using `pandoc-citepro`c to the new `citeproc`. I have not found a simple example for usage of `citeproc` and have difficulties to use it.

Specifically, I do not see how to construct the `list of references` and `list of citations`.

For the `list of references`, I assume I should process the `bib` file as it was done with, e.g.

```
parseBibTex :: String -> IO [Entry.T]
```

what is the corresponding function?

I cannot see how to extract the list of citations and how to produce the formatted file.

Perhaps I misunderstood that `citeproc` was a replacement for `pandoc-citeproc`. I think it would be extremely useful to see a simple complete example how a text converted to pandoc format and a reference `bib` file would be processed to obtain a formated text file. I think I could work from such an example...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The functions you want for processing a Pandoc document with citeproc are not in citeproc itself but in Pandoc's Citeproc module:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.16.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Citeproc.html
These functions handle all of the details for you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was mislead by the note in hackages, which says `pandoc-citeproc (deprecated in favor of citeproc)` which made me believe that I should only use functions from `citeproc` and remove all the ones from `pandoc-citeproc`. Perhaps you could remove this `depreceated` notice in hackage?